# How to get shipping cost before payment form?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, payment, checkout

I would like to get the **shipping cost** before payment, but I can't as the user choose its delivery options only on checkout and not in the cart page. So I cannot get this data from `WC->cart`, neither of `$order` because the order hasn't been created yet.

If it is possible, I would like to display this data with the hook `woocommerce_review_order_before_payment` because this is where I want my data to be displayed.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, In this case, you need to use particular hooks for the checkout page or that plugin you are using if any hook is available wherever you want to show display your shipping cost.

For example, I have posted the shipping cost above the billing form using `woocommerce_before_checkout_form` hook.

```
function get_all_shipping_rates() {
    $delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
    foreach ((array) $delivery_zones as $key => $the_zone ) {
        foreach ($the_zone['shipping_methods'] as $value) {
            ?>
            <ul>
                <li><?php echo $value->method_title; ?><strong> <?php echo $value->cost; ?></strong></li>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'get_all_shipping_rates');
```

Code Tested and works at my end.

Comment: Actually, I'm not talking about that. I would like to display programmatically the shipping cost at a specific location in the checkout (I'm working with a multistep step checkout plugin and I would like to retrieve this information at the last step before the user pays).